# How do I create a video presentation with preset pause-points?

Tags: video, blender, pause, voiceover, presentations

I want to create a video that has preset pause-points to use in a presentation.

My presentation goes like this:

1. I present the first video segment while doing live voice-over. It will automatically pause at a preset point.
2. While the video is still paused, I give more information related to the subtopic at hand.
3. Then I move on to the next video segment, doing another live voice-over.
4. While the video is paused, I talk some more.
5. Repeat.

I figured this would be useful especially in presenting 3D drawings. I also liked the progressive line charts presented by Al Gore in his An Inconvenient Truth.

I'm on Windows XP and I know how to use Blender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if that satisfies you, but why don't you edit the videos to make different parts. You need 2 pauses, so you create three parts, and in your presentation, a mouse click would start the next part. It would be easy to implement and it should do the trick for you.